# minimise application in android problem

Tags: android

when application installed and opend first time,and i pressed home key then application minimises normally.but when i starts same application(not minimised one),it shows me blank screen.this happens only first time.i am not getting what happens..can any body help

Comment: Plz, add the code. I guess you are doing all the login in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: thanks for giving replay...in oncreate i am just starting..intent..that is just going from one page to other

Comment: Android applications do not 'minimize'  Please read up on the activity lifecycle on developer.android.com

Comment: thanks for giving reply  ...butwhen i first time open the app.and press home key it goes to background and same app if i opens fress one,only blank screen displays.at the same time if i press back key from handset,fresh application starts..is this some different behavior.??

Answer (score 0):

When you starts a fresh application, it first call onCreate then onStart then onResume
When you press home key it will call onPause then onStop
So when you start it again (by clicking its icon) it call onRestart then onStart then onResume, will not call onCreate here
So if you feel some different behavior, then check the code in any of these function if you Override them

Refer this link also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: you are right friend...but my case is that..whatever behavior i mentioned happens only for appliaction when i installed app and opens for first time

Comment: That means you have done all the work in oncreate(). Just change to onStart(), it may work